# Error al importar page Ionic

Tags: android, ionic, angular

La page que quiero importar funciona muy bien en una page que la llama en un evento anterior (Login) pero ahora no puedo importar ninguna, es como si se fuera truncado en proyecto

Cuando quiero importar una page dentro de otra page predefinida en app.module me genera el siguiente error

> ```
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MainPage -> PersonaEventoPage]: 
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MainPage -> PersonaEventoPage]: 
>     NullInjectorError: No provider for PersonaEventoPage!
>
>
> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MainPage -> PersonaEventoPage]: 
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MainPage -> PersonaEventoPage]: 
>     NullInjectorError: No provider for PersonaEventoPage!
>     at _NullInjector.get (vendor.js:1376)
>     at resolveToken (vendor.js:1674)
>     at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:1616)
>     at StaticInjector.get (vendor.js:1484)
>     at resolveToken (vendor.js:1674)
>     at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:1616)
>     at StaticInjector.get (vendor.js:1484)
>     at resolveNgModuleDep (vendor.js:11228)
>     at NgModuleRef_.get (vendor.js:12461)
>     at resolveDep (vendor.js:12951)
>     at _NullInjector.get (vendor.js:1376)
>     at resolveToken (vendor.js:1674)
>     at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:1616)
>     at StaticInjector.get (vendor.js:1484)
>     at resolveToken (vendor.js:1674)
>     at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:1616)
>     at StaticInjector.get (vendor.js:1484)
>     at resolveNgModuleDep (vendor.js:11228)
>     at NgModuleRef_.get (vendor.js:12461)
>     at resolveDep (vendor.js:12951)
>     at c (polyfills.js:3)
>     at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
>     at NavControllerBase._fireError (vendor.js:51758)
>     at NavControllerBase._failed (vendor.js:51751)
>     at vendor.js:51798
>     at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
>     at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:5123)
>     at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
>     at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
>     at polyfills.js:3
> ```

Mi app module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { ScreenSplashPage } from '../pages/screen-splash/screen-splash';
import { ActividadLoginPage } from '../pages/actividad-login/actividad-login';
import { DatabaseProvider } from '../providers/database/database';
import { DeseosPersonaPage } from '../pages/deseos-persona/deseos-persona';
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { WsProvider } from '../providers/ws/ws';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MainPage } from '../pages/main/main';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { InternetListenerProvider } from '../providers/internet-listener/internet-listener';
import { MapaDireccionPage } from './../pages/mapa-direccion/mapa-direccion';
import { PersonaEventoPage } from '../pages/persona-evento/persona-evento';
import { InvitacionesPage } from '../pages/invitaciones/invitaciones';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        ScreenSplashPage,
        ActividadLoginPage,
        DeseosPersonaPage,
        MainPage,
        MapaDireccionPage,
        PersonaEventoPage,
        InvitacionesPage
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        ScreenSplashPage,
        ActividadLoginPage,
        DeseosPersonaPage,
        MainPage,
        MapaDireccionPage,
        PersonaEventoPage,
        InvitacionesPage
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        SQLite,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
        DatabaseProvider,
        WsProvider,
        Network,
        InternetListenerProvider
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: ¿Esa nueva *Page* está importada en el módulo?

Comment: Si, como digo se está utilizando en otra page

Comment: Me refiero si está también definido en app.module.ts

Comment: Si, ella está definida

Comment: Puedes añadir tu fichero app.module.ts a la pregunta? El error es porque Angular intenta buscar un servicio no declarado en el `providers` del módulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione agregando un arreglo al objeto providers en la Page en la que necesitaba importar con las variables de importación de la page

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [SiguientePaginaPage]
})
```

El TypeScript completo quedaría de esta forma

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SiguientePaginaPage } from '../siguiente-pagina/siguiente-pagina';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [SiguientePaginaPage]
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public siguientePaginaPage:SiguientePaginaPage) {
    console.log(siguientePaginaPage.variable);
  }

}
```